# TFS2015 Run Functional Tests - Windows Security prompt for credentials

Tags: visual-studio, selenium, tfs, automated-tests, tfs-2015

I'm running functional tests(selenium) on remote test machines.

[image]

Sadly when i started using multiple test machines i get Windows Security prompt for credentials while Run Functional Tests step is performed on remote machine.

[image]

When i enter credentials set for Test Agent, functional tests starts but after restarting the test machine...
This prompt occurs each time when i start build with functional tests.
I tried to add/remove credentials in Credential Manager but each time new Credential for PersonalAccessToken is added.
I thought that setting same account name with same password on each machine may be the reason, but i changed it and this still occurs.
Anyone faced this problem before?

[image]

Comment: Did you try with a AD credential? How's the result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The account that you use in the Test Agent deployment step needs to have access to TFS.

This is not authenticated using PAS but AD credentials, the same ones that are used to run the service.